# How to get Not Installed Plugins in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

[image]I am new to QGIS.

I am trying to export the Voronoi polygon Coordinates to CSV.

I have searched in net for that mmqgis plugin has to be installed but after installing the software in manage and plugin tools, not installed option is not showing.

How do I install that plugin and is there any other way to export?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.

Comment: If "not installed option is not showing" then that sounds like it is installed. Have you got a "mmqgis" item in the main menubar in QGIS now?

Comment: Do you need CSV? If you want a text version of coordinates of a polygon you will probably find WKT is more useful.  To get WKT easily, firstly in the options of QGIS, do to the attributes tab and select `copy attributes with WKT`. Then open the attribute table for the layer and press the button to invert selection. This will highlight all the records in the attribute table. Press the copy button. Paste into a text editor or spreadsheet.

Comment: Thanks for the Suggestion Sir. I didn't get "mmqgis"  in main menubar. Actually, I imported coordinates and I have drawn Voronoi polygon. I want to get those Voronoi polygon coordinates from each node. In "Attributes" option only the coordinates which I took initially, that only showing sir.

Answer (score 3):

Open the plug-in manage and install dialog from the menu (**Plugins/Manage and Install plugins...**).

[image]

1. Select not installed plugins
2. start typing the name of the plugin in Search field (mm)
3. Select the mmqgis plugin from the list
4. Click on the install plugin button

Comment: Thank u Sir. But that ''Not installed'' option itself is not showing in Plugins window.

Comment: @VidhyaAmirthavalli - Make sure you have access to the internet and then go to the `Settings` option as shown in the image. There should be a `Reload repository` button, click on this and you should get access to plugins stored online and check which ones you don't have installed =)

Comment: I have Internet Connection. Sir,to access internet in QGIS software, do we need to do any settings in "options" tool. I am using "QGIS 2.18.2" version

Comment: @VidhyaAmirthavalli - Please check if http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/plugins.xml is a given repository in the Plugins | Setting dialog.

Comment: I am using college wifi.Because of that, I couldn't access internet. I did proxy settings in "Settings > Options> Network " . Now I got "Not installed" option and installed "mmqgis" plugin.